# Vertical alignment of menukeys output in tables

Tags: tables, menukeys

I want to collect a number of menu entries and associated shortcuts in a table with additional information and references. The actual table is quite large, so here is an abbreviated example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    Menu & Key & Whatever \\
    \hline
    \menu{Foo > Bar} & \keys{F1} & Go To Next Bar \\
    \hline
    \menu{Baz > Boo > Far} & \keys{F5} & Go To Remote Bar \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I need the `\hlines` or something equivalent because the table takes up entire landscape pages and users need to be able to visually follow the table lines.

The problem is that the output of the macros `\menu` and `keys` is not centered vertically in the table lines:
[image: problem]

As you can see, the output is very close to the upper margin of each table line. Is there a way to adjust this globally -- or add a bit of height to the table lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert a vertical strut inside each row so that to introduce a gap as needed. Alternatively, use [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and avoid excessive use of `\hline` (and especially vertical rules):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{menukeys,array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\rule{0pt}{0.8\normalbaselineskip}}l|l|l|}
  \hline
  Menu & Key & Whatever \\
  \hline
  \menu{Foo > Bar} & \keys{F1} & Go To Next Bar \\
  \hline
  \menu{Baz > Boo > Far} & \keys{F5} & Go To Remote Bar \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
  Menu & Key & Whatever \\
  \midrule
  \menu{Foo > Bar} & \keys{F1} & Go To Next Bar \\
  \menu{Baz > Boo > Far} & \keys{F5} & Go To Remote Bar \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is typically a case for the `cellspace` package: it lets you define minimal distances between the top of a cell to the above line/cell and between the bottom of a cell and the below cell/line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|Sl|l|l|}
\hline
Menu & Key & Whatever \\
\hline
\menu{Foo > Bar} & \keys{F1} & Go To Next Bar \\
\hline
\menu{Baz > Boo > Far} & \keys{F5} & Go To Remote Bar \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very promising. The problem is: While it works in the MWE, I get "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup" errors in existing tables as soon as I add the package to the preamble - without even using the new column modifier...

Comment: Could I see the code, or at least a MWE that shows the problem?